# How to introduce the method used in a research

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Which of the following sentences are correct? why? and how to make it proper?

> Our approach to dealing with the problem A was of method B.

we can also introduce method B as follows:

> Our approach to dealing with the problem A was by using/employing method B.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please explain what you are unsure about.

Comment: I am unsure about what we are introducing as our approach; we can simply mention the name of a method as above; or we can say that our approach was by using (or by employing) a method. which one works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

> Our approach to dealing with problem A was method B.

(or, slightly more natural)

> Method B was our approach to dealing with problem A.

The article 'the' should be left out - the 'A' already indicates you are dealing with a particular problem.

Also, leave out 'of' - it doesn't make sense in this context, because you are describing the approach itself, and not a property/quality of it:

> Our approach to dealing with problem A was of high value to them.

Comment: Agreed, yet there are some special cases where 'of' is justified.  For instance, if "method B" describes a set of approaches, you can say that your approach was *of* that kind, IOW, from that set.

Comment: If we say: "Our approach to dealing with problem A is by using method B"
is this also correct?